How I can select the code tags that do not have a CSS class?
I have multiple code elements inside a paragraph like so:
<p>
   Some text <code>Some code</code> more text 
   <code class="verbatim">verbatim text</code>
   and even more <code>text</code>
</p>

I want to select all code block inside paragraphs except those who have the "verbatim" class.

You'll have to define the code first and override in code.verbatim.

p code:not(.verbatim) should work

Try p code:not(.verbatim)


p code:not(.verbatim) {
  background: lightblue;
}
<p>
  Some text <code>Some code</code> more text
  <code class="verbatim">verbatim text</code> and even more <code>text</code>
</p>




Thank you. Can I also use p > code:not(.verbatim) ?

You could but it seems unnecessary.
